# Ubuntu команда systemctl ругается на запуск uwsgi с логированием

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uwsgi

Команда systemctl restart myapp.service проходит успешно и uwsgi перезапускается, но мне нужно логирование uwsgi с ключом --logto и если я его добавляю то вываливается ошибка

```
#myapp.service
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor
After=syslog.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data
# Requires systemd version 211 or newer
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all
User=www-data
Group=www-data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

А вот такой конфиг уже не работает

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor
After=syslog.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data --logto /var/log/uwsgi.log
# Requires systemd version 211 or newer
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all
User=www-data
Group=www-data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

И выдает ошибку

```
myapp.service - uWSGI Emperor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/garda2.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Tue 2018-12-11 00:17:11 UTC; 3s ago
  Process: 614 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data --logto /var/log/uwsgi.log (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 614 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "initializing uWSGI"

Dec 11 00:17:11 151-248-118-242 systemd[1]: garda2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 11 00:17:11 151-248-118-242 systemd[1]: garda2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 11 00:17:11 151-248-118-242 systemd[1]: garda2.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 11 00:17:11 151-248-118-242 systemd[1]: Stopped uWSGI Emperor.
Dec 11 00:17:11 151-248-118-242 systemd[1]: garda2.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 11 00:17:11 151-248-118-242 systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI Emperor.
Dec 11 00:17:11 151-248-118-242 systemd[1]: garda2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 11 00:17:11 151-248-118-242 systemd[1]: garda2.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

При этом в файле rc.local стоит вторая конфигурация:

```
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data --logto /var/log/uwsgi.log
```

И при перезапуске сервере логирование идет нормально.

Прошу помощи, сам уже и не знаю то делать, новчик в linux(

Comment: Есть мнение™, что юзер `www-data` не имеет права записи в каталог `/var/log` или в файл `/var/log/uwsgi.log`

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Спасибо за мнение) Пытался под root сделать, все точно также
Если я запускаю команду в не systemctl, а на прямую в командной строке то все нормально отрабатывает, а тут получается что ошибка выбивается при запуске самой команды(

Comment: Мне остаётся только повториться: проверьте права на log-файл и на каталог, в котором он находится. При необходимости измените либо права, либо пользователя, от которого systemd запускает uwsgi, смотря что вам подсказывает ваше разумение безопасности.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev от root пытался запустит, эффект такой же...